# Sorting of strings with fixed length

Tags: java, bucket, radix-sort

I want to sort Integers. Therefore I interpret them as binary strings of length 32. Now I am able to apply bucketsort for each component. Here is my implementation in java:

```
public static void sort(List<Integer> numbers)
{
    Queue<Integer> tmp =new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        tmp.offer(numbers.get(i));
    }

    List<Integer>[] bucket = new ArrayList[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
        bucket[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    for (int k = 32; k > 0; k--) {
        // Clear
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
            bucket[i].clear();
        }

        while (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
            Integer firstel =tmp.element();
            String el =String.valueOf(firstel);

            if (el.charAt(k - 1) == 0) {
                bucket[0].add(firstel);
            } else {
                bucket[1].add(firstel);
            }
            tmp.remove();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
            for (Integer j : bucket[i]) {
                tmp.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure, whether my code deals right with these binary strings. Do I have to convert the integers from the list numbers to binary strings?
Note: It is only for practice. There is no deeper sense concerning time complexity.

Comment: Before anything: _why_? String conversion and then radix sorting with rather slow string extraction them sounds a heck of a lot slower than just sorting your integers either with a quick sort, or a radix sort based on bit masking. How many integers are we talking about here?

Comment: It's just for practice. Is my code correct?

Comment: Please mention that in your post. It makes this a very different problem, with a very different answer, compared to if you were trying to implement this in order to actually sort numerical data =)

Comment: When I have my list numbers containing integers, do I have to convert them to binary strings?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I did edit my post.

Comment: No, there is no reason to: use bit logic if you need to work with bits: `final int BIT_ONE_MASK = 0x1; ...; if (BIT_ONE_MASK == (i & BIT_ONE_MASK)) { bit one is set } else { it's not, do the other thing }` (of course, you wouldn't use individual declarations for each bit mask, you generate an array of 32 of them with a for loop and a bit shift)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Thank you:) My problem is, that I do not know, how test my method. I I create an ArrayList of integers, the numbers won'tinterpreted as 32 bit integers. So how can I test my method?

Comment: When testing, start small: don't generate "a list of numbers", start by testing with a very short list of known numbers that not sorted already, like `10,4` and then step through your program in debug more: at ever line, is it updating your various lists in the way you expected it to? Cool. Add one more number, like `10, 100,4` and step through one more time: are things still doing what you expected them to at each line?

Comment: One important hint, though, is that bucket sort runs three operations: [scatter, sort, and gather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort). Your code shows the scatter and gather steps, but I don't see any code for sorting the buckets _before_ gathering them up again.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I don't have to sort the buckets. The algorithm guarantees, that after the 32-th iteration the lost is sorted. I don't see how my code can deal with binary strings?

Comment: I've rewritten your code (with explanations) as an answer, and by throwing away the string conversion logic, the resulting code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first rewrite this a bit, because there is no need for Queues, or a tmp arraylist, etc. Step one, a stub class that lets us write less code:

```
private class Numlist extends ArrayList<Integer> {
  Numlist() { super(); }
}
```

Done, we no longer need to write `ArrayList<Integer>` everywhere.

Now, java does "autoboxing" so anything that you store Integers in can do `int`, and vice versa. That's handy, because we can throw away all that string stuff. We don't need it if we just care about bit comparison:

```
public void sort(Numlist numbers) {
  // No copying `numbers` to a `tmp` queue: just work with it directly.
  Numlist zeroes, ones;

  for (int k = 1; k < 32; k++) {
    // Build this step's masking value, which we can use to
    // find the value of individual bits by using bitwise AND.
    // Also note that we _know_ this is a safe integer operation.
    mask = (int) Math.pow(2,k);

    // just allocate new lists; it's about as fast as clearing.
    zeroes = new Numlist();
    ones = new Numlist();

    // "scatter": now we empty the numbers list one element at a
    //  time, and then we'll fill it back up after we emptied it.
    while (!numbers.isEmpty()) {
      int e = numbers.remove(0);

      if ((e & mask) == mask) {
        ones.add(e);
      } else {
        zeroes.add(e);
      }        
    }

    // "gather"
    for (int i: zeroes) { numbers.add(i); }
    for (int i: ones) { numbers.add(i); }      
  }
}
```

And with that rewrite, things work. We removed a lot of verbosity which makes it easier to reason about what the code does, and we removed the whole "int to string to substring, then char comparison" which means there's a lot less to go wrong.

In terms of testing, add your function into the following class:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

  // private class goes here

  public static void main(String[] argv) { new Test(); }

  public Test() {
    Numlist list = new Numlist();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(77810);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(100);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(290387423);
    list.add(23423);
    sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
  }

  // function goes here
}
```

And done: `javac` will happily compile it, and executing should yield `[1, 4, 10, 100, 23423, 77810, 290387423]`

You'll also note we're not using `for (int k = 31; k > 0; k--)` but we're using `for (int k=1; k<32; k++)`... why? Does it make a difference?

**it makes a huge difference**

By running our mask from b000...001 to b100...000 we guarantee that despite "picking values back out", their relative "less than the current bit" ordering is preserved.

If we run our masking the other way, from b1000...000 to b000...001, then at every step we're undoing the ordering we just set up, and the result is not a sorted list at all: `[1, 4, 100, 77810, 10, 290387423, 23423]`

** edit **: why does masking work?

The integer types `byte`, `char`, `int` and `long` are just bit patterns of 1, 2, 4, and 8 bytes, respectively, so all of these are already "binary numbers", we just need a way to access individual bits, which we can do using [bitwise masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

In order to mask off "everything but a specific bit", you can take the bitwise AND of some bit pattern, and a pattern in which only a single bit is set, which we can create *really easily* since these are just numbers that are "powers of 2".

For instance, to check the bits in the number 23, we can use the following checks:

```
     23  &   1     2    4      8     16    32  

b0    1  &  1=1   0=0   0=0   0=0   0=0   0=0
b1    1  &  0=0   1=1   0=0   0=0   0=0   0=0
b2    1  &  0=0   0=0   1=1   0=0   0=0   0=0
b3    0  &  0=0   0=0   0=0   1=0   0=0   0=0
b4    1  &  0=0   0=0   0=0   0=0   1=1   0=0
b5    0  &  0=0   0=0   0=0   0=0   0=0   1=0
```

Here we can see the number 23, binary `10111`, and the result of masking by each power of two: 23 & 1 yields 1, so we know the first bit is set. We see that 23 & 2 yields 2, so we know the second bit is set. The same for 4, but 23 & 8 yields 0. We know that the fourth bit is *not* set.

So we can check any length bit pattern by using bitwise AND: if `(number & mask) == mask` we know that the bit for that mask is set. If the result is 0 instead, we know the bit was not set.

Also, note that `&` is **not** the same as `&&`: `&` is a bitwise AND operation, performing an AND for every single bit between the left and right hand side of the operator. The `&&` operator is *logical* AND, requiring the left and right sides to boolean values. The logic AND is effectively "a single AND", whereas the bitwise AND is "as many AND operations as there are bits to test".

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and for your explanations. My only problem is to understand how the code 'interprets' the integers as binary strings. Your code says:  if (k > 0) mask = (int) Math.pow(2,k); In  each iteration you consider another  component. I am not able to understand how the code 'sees' for example 32 as binary sequence?

Comment: `byte`, `char`, `int` and `longint` are just bit patterns of 1, 2, 4, and 8 bytes (typically), so all of them already _are_ a binary number, and we can make use of that fact by using bitwise operators: & performs an AND on the _bits_ of the left and right, so `23 & 8` gives 0 because 10111 and 01000 have no 1's in common. That's what we exploit: that Math.pow(2,k) gives us a number with a single bit set to 1. 0=`0`, 1=`1`, 2=`10`,4=`100`,8=`1000`, etc. We then use that mask to test "whatever number is in the list" because `number & mask` _has_ to be equal to `mask` if they share that single 1

Comment: Note that this is very different from if we used `&&` which is _logical_ operation, used to compare booleans (e.g. "true && false" is "false"). `&` is a _bitwise_ operation, used with numbers (e.g. "24 & 8" is treated as "11000 & 01000", and results in "01000" because only the second bit is 1 in both left and right terms)

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now. Sorry that it took so long:( But I learned a lot:)

Answer (score -2):

Java already provides a convinient api as part of Collections framework. 
Collections.sort(numbers);
This will sort the integers in ascending order. Incase if you need different ordering, you can use another api which also takes Comparator.

Comment: This is not OP. Your answer is deviating from it. OP wants to write his own bucket sort and not use existing ones.

Comment: Yes I want to write my own specific bucket sort algorithm.